# WPF Programmatically set the DataBinding for a DataGridTextColumn's DisplayIndex

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I currently generate my `DataGridTextColumn`s for my DataGrid programmatically. I set their databinding with `textColumn.Binding = new Binding(BindingName);`. This sets the databinding for the content of that column to a property within the array that the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` is bound to.

However I also want to bind the `DisplayIndex` property of the column to properties in my ViewModel.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to go about setting up the databinding for the `DataGridTextColumn`'s by itself. How do I go about this?

DataGrid:

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="QuickStatsDataGrid"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding QuickStatistics.UserQuickStats}"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.RowSpan="2"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Top">  
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The Method that creates the column:

```
    private void AddColumn()
    {
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        textColumn.Header = Name;
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding(BindingName);
        textColumn.MinWidth = 20;
        TextColumn = textColumn;
        CreatedColumn = true;
        DataGridOwner.Columns.Add(textColumn); // Datagrid owner is the DataGrid
    }
```

Edit: The appropriate properties are in my ViewModel. It doesn't seem necessary to post the ViewModel, lets assume there is a property named `ColumnDisplayIndex` in `MyViewModel`.

Edit: Addition to my method. The properties in the ViewModel don't seem to update when I change the index programmaticly or by dragging the column over to a new location.

```
    private void AddColumn()
    {
        DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(textColumn, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, new Binding(DisplayIndexBindingName) { Source = viewModel });

        textColumn.DisplayIndex = Index;
        textColumn.Header = Name;
        textColumn.Binding = new Binding(BindingName);
        textColumn.MinWidth = 20;
        TextColumn = textColumn;
        CreatedColumn = true;
        DataGridOwner.Columns.Add(textColumn); // Datagrid owner is the DataGrid
    }
```

Comment: each column has different DisplayIndex, so that means your View-model should have different corresponding bound values for displayindex, so where are they?

Comment: I have the appropriate properties in my ViewModel for each items display index. However, I don't know how to bind a specific property of the `DataGridTextColumn` to them. It seems unnecessary to post the ViewModel, lets just assume there is an int property named `ColumDisplayIndex` in `MyViewModel`.

Comment: do you have access to your view-model inside the `AddColumn` method?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If it's necessary I can pass a reference of the ViewModel to the object containing the `AddColumn` method.

Comment: so it's just easy like that. The `Binding` can be setup like  `BindingOperations.SetBinding(textColumn, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, new Binding("ColumnDisplayIndex") { Source = yourViewModel});`

Comment: Thanks! The BindingOperations is new to me, really handy. Before I try this, if I have a static source for this ViewModel set up in App.XAML, is it still necessary to pass the ViewModel reference in?

Comment: do you mean you set it in `Resources` of the main Window or of some other element?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Setting it's source that the Resource of the window would be preferable over setting the source via passing the ViewModel reference. I just gave it a try and the Properties in the ViewModel are not being updated when the DisplayIndex of the column is being changed.  My addition:          `BindingOperations.SetBinding(textColumn, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, new Binding(DisplayIndexBindingName) { Source = viewModel });`

Comment: not sure what you mean, are columns shown in the correct order initially? you can try changing the `DisplayIndexBindingName` of each column in the order different from the adding order to see if it works initially.

Comment: The columns show in the correct order since I am setting their `DisplayIndex` manually in the `AddColumn` method. However the properties they are supposed to bind to do not change values when the index is changed, and changing the properties values does not change the index of the column as if there was no DataBinding.

Comment: Tried a boatload of different approaches with this `BindingOperations.SetBinding` method from different SO questions with no success. I could just subscribe to the `ColumnDisplayIndexChanged` event and work with it from there, though that far less elegant than the databinding.

Comment: I'm not so sure what is wrong here but sometimes changing the property while it is bound (in your case this `textColumn.DisplayIndex = Index;`) may break the binding. You can try setting the `Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay` to see if it works.

Comment: Figured it out, for some reason referencing my view-model didn't work, which is odd since it's the same object. I had to use `Source = App.Current.FindResource("MainScreenViewModel")` for it to function.